# Building a Webpack 4 Config for SASS (Compilation, Minification in Prod), JS (Concat + Minification), and Multiple Vue Single Page Applications

Tags: javascript, webpack

Trying to setup a webpack setup for my entire resource generation workflow in our app. I don't need any hot reloading, browsersync, etc. Just needs to watch for changes, and rebuild depedent objects when changes are made. File structure looks like this:

[image: Folder Structure]
(I apologize for the image I seriously looked up other methods to post structure, but nothing was working on the preview, I can post a fiddle-or-codepen with this output in a comment afterwards)

The only areas of note are:

1) Each folder underneath **vue-spas** each Single-Page Mini App (SPAs) generates it's own output file of the app.
2) All items in constructs underneath js are concat and minified into one output file (/dist/js/main.min.js) but every item underneath js/components/ just renders a minified and mangled version of that file

Lastly, I understand this is probably a difficult question to wrap around, but I have Gulp doing some of it now, and Webpack doing the Vue compilation, just trying to see if it's possible to consolidate into just webpack and let it do the work.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Seth-Duncan/full/abbZOgp For Directory Output

Answer (score 1):

There are a few approaches. The simplest would be to add a key for each app in the [entry point configuration](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) in your `webpack.config.js` file.

That would look like this in your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app1: './vue-spa/vue-spa1/app.js',
    app2: './vue-spa/vue-spa2/app.js'
    // etc
  }
};
```

This will output individual directories in your `dist` for each with a nicely bundled app file.

By default, if you pass in a production variable to your webpack build command it'll apply all the optimizations you're looking for. If it's lacking out-of-the-box, there's likely a loader that can handle whatever optimization you need.

For Sass, you can add `sass-loader` to your webpack file:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Your `devServer` can just watch your `vue-spa` directory recursively for changes.

Another approach is to use `lerna` -- though that would require additional configuration, and is only necessary in your situation if you're in an enterprise environment where each individual app is being shipped out to a private NPM registry, and require individual semver.